# Logstash grok pattern for date

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I have the logs in the following format and I want to parse the date out of it using the logstash grok pattern in logstash filter:

```
[31/1/20 4:31:31:697 IST]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This solution must work (put it in your configuration file of logstash) :

```
filter{
grok {
   match => { "field" => "\[%{DATESTAMP:date} %{WORD:code}\]" }
 }
}
```

Be carefull, your second value looks like strange (*31:697*)

You could debug the grok pattern with the online tool [grokdebug](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).